# Struts-jqGrid-plugin not displaying timestamp

Tags: jqgrid, timestamp, struts2-jquery

I'm using **Struts2-jqGrid-plugin** in a web project to display my data from a remote database.
Now I got confused when i'm trying to display the date in the json result.
In the struts-action, the query result are in a list. This is the src-format of my timestamp in json response from server side:

```
addtime: "2013-03-05T13:08:14"
dob: "1990-01-01T00:00:00"
```

Initially, this property in my list is timestamp type, somehow, in json response, it became this kind of format. On my page, jgGrid date formatter just show a &nbsp& for this column. Two above columns both not working.

```
<s:url var="ShowSubjectAction" action="showUserSubjects"
            namespace="Subject" />
    <sjg:grid gridModel="gridModel" id="SubjectGrid"
            caption="Subject Gird" dataType="json" href="%{ShowSubjectAction}"
            rowList="2,5,10,15" rowNum="2" rownumbers="true" pager="true"
            autowidth="true" height="200">
            <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID" formatter="integer"
                sortable="false" />
            <sjg:gridColumn name="gender" index="gender" title="Gender"
                formatter="integer" />
            <sjg:gridColumn name="D.o.B" index="dob" title="D.o.B"
                formatter="date"
                formatoptions="{'srcformat':'Y-m-d H:i:sO','newformat':'d/m/Y'}" />
            <sjg:gridColumn name="AddTime" index="addtime" title="AddTime"
                formatter="date" />
    </sjg:grid>
```

Is there any way to dispay it properly just by using jqGrid date formatter rather than converting it on my server side? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation you will see the date/time formatters that are availible to you, and if those are not enough you can always set your own custom formatter and parse the value and reformat it yourself.

Documentation:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter

Example of custom formatter:

```
 formatter: customTimeFormatter, unformat: customTimeUnformatter,
```

Functions:

```
function customTimeFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
....

function customTimeUnformatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After some re-reading those docs, i found that i should use json annotation to prepare my date on the server side. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark correct if this put you on the right path.